# CSS causing page not to display on iPad / iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad

One of my designers sliced up a PSD & for some reason the page isn't rendering on iPhones or iPads. The div that contains a feedback link is the only thing that is visible. I've spent some time on the issue, but can't seem to find the issue. Have a look here: http://bit.ly/jNcJ47

Comment: Whatever your problem is, it affects Safari/Mac also. Chrome/Mac is OK.

Comment: If it is also a safari issue you could try to add the css (thats not working) just to safari like this: `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
#div {margin-left: 10px;}}` That may also clear up the other issues, or it may not (I never programed for an iphone so I have no clue
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same problem in Safari on my Mac. I messed around with the Web Inspector for a few minutes and found out that when I disable the `sidebar1` element's `height:` attribute, the content appears.

Answer (score 1):

that's because the width occupied by the sidebar1 div is making the rest drop to the bottom! and since your container div has the overflow hidden, it doesn't even show the other floatted divs that dropped.

I advise positioning that div absolutelly and you're done.